# WinUI3 CommunityToolkit MVVM Messenger calling on disposed objects?

Tags: c#, mvvm, winui

I am using the WeakReferenceMessenger in CommunityToolkit.MVVM in my WinUI3.

It is my understanding that by using the WeakReferenceMessager I do not need to worry about the recipient object's lifetime.

So, I have an object that is a recipient, that gets disposed. I am finding that the next time a message to which it was subscribed is sent by the messenger, my disposed object has its Receive() method called, resulting in a ObjectDisposedException and a crash.

How can I prevent this? The object in question is a UserControl-derived class, so I don't know, nor have control over, when the GC disposes of the instance.

I am using version 8.2.2. of CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Just don't use it with usercontrol but with underlying view model... Also weak references are more about that "they don't count" for gc when it considers when to free object and not lifecycle per se

Comment: @Selvin is correct, use it with the VM if possible. If that is not an option, you need to properly register and unregister the messages, for example the `Loaded` and `Unloaded` events.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I had a feeling the Messenger was primarily designed for VM to VM communication, but I didn't see any reasons why it couldn't be used within View components. And, the messages that I need to respond to really do make more sense at the View layer than the VM layer (these messages communicate changes to the presentation of the data, not the data itself).  The advice to `RegisterAll` and `UnregisterAll` in the `Loaded` and `Unloaded` events is a very good solution. Thank you.

Comment: BTW the GC has nothing to do with disposing. It is only a state of an instance and it is by definition unusable when in disposed state. You have take care to not use the instance in that unusable state.